# Plus-minus style in package explorer of eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am on Eclipse Juno, and my package explorer shows the hierarchy of package and classes by means of an arrow sign. How can I change this to a plus-minus combination style, also a plus-minus style will have lines connecting the hierarchy which is now missing in the arrow-style.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: I don't know of any way to change this. Eclipse uses the native tree control for whatever platform you are running on so you get what the native control uses.